# DjangoCMS - Placeholders in templates do not show up in django cms structure view

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm using djangoCMS to add CMS functionality in my website templates but the placeholders i have placed on the placed are not showing up, i have defined my `CMS_TEMPLATES` IN MY `settings.py` and put the `{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags sorl_thumbnail %}` on my `base.html` and also added `{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags  %}` on my other templates that expand the `base.html`, but when i log into djangoCMS admin and visit my pages i find no placeholders in my `structure view`. what could be the problem here?

`settings.py`

```py
CMS_TEMPLATES = [
    ('index.html','Home'),
    ('solutions.html','solutions'),
    ('commercial.html','Commercial Solar Solution'),
    ('residential.html','Residential Solar Solution'),
    ('on-grid.html','On grid solutions'),
    ('off-grid.html','Off Grid solutions'),
    ('water-heating.html','Solar Water Heating'),
    ('solar-water-pumping.html','Solar water pumping'),
    ('hybrid-grid.html','Hybrid Solutions'),
    ('outdoor-lighting.html','Outdoor Lighting'),
    ('contacts.html','Contacts'),
    ('terms-of-use.html','Terms of use'),
]
```

`base.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}

    {% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags  %}
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% render_block "css" %}
</head>

<body>{% cms_toolbar %}
    <ul> {% show_menu 0 0 100 100 %} </ul>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <div class="div">
        <img src="{% static 'administration/css/images/icons/logo.png' %}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <ul class="navlist">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'administration:about' %}">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'administration:blog' %}">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="{% static 'administration/css/images/icons/logo.png' %}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
</nav>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% render_block "js" %}

</body>
</html>
```

`solutions.html`

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Commercial pv solar heating solutions {% 
    endblock %}

    {% load static  %}
    {% load cms_tags %}
    {% block content %}

        <div class="water__heating--section">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6 solutions__content--image" id="commercial__banner--image">

                    <h4 class="small__title">support and Evaluation</h4>
                    <div class="small__content small__content--default">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima soluta nesciunt consequuntur esse consectetur
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 solutions__content--box">

                <h1 class="heavy__title"> We Can Help your business <span class="emphasis">go solar</span> </h1>
                <div class="small__content ribbon__content--default">
                        {% placeholder "commercial section one" %}
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your child template (which extends base template) there is should be something like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        {% placeholder "feature" %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% placeholder "content" %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% placeholder "splashbox" %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

And base template should looks like this:

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}This is my new project home page{% endblock title %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% cms_toolbar %}
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
            </ul>
            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried that but still placeholders do not appear

Comment: @DennisGathagu Did CMS_TEMPLATES point to the correct child template? Can you show your templates and CMS_TEMPLATES setting?

Comment: @DennisGathagu i've tried your example and it works for me. Be sure that you are using correct child template https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jnya5f5cy4ap21/Screenshot%202018-02-28%2014.49.36.png?dl=0

Comment: i have managed to show the placeholders like you have above but as soon as i add content to the text plugins i can see the page populated with my content as normal but once i publish and exit the edit view or navigate to another page the content doesnt show up on the placeholders in my template, i just get blank fields